# POD file not being loaded

Tags: cocos3d

I have been trying myself to understand Cocos3D app development. The big hurdle what i find is that POD is not being loaded. I used Collada2POD converter to convert to POD, where the Collada file was actually exported from blender. I tried downloading SDK's and converter, but still the same. I really can't figure out what is the actual problem with my POD. PVRShaman tool is used to verify the POD and it says POD is fine. Can someone help me to figure out the actual problem.

Note: I am working on MacLion 10.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself..

I forgot to set the scale and location of the material (in my case a cube) in blender. Now its loaded and i can see it rotating. Export the material as a Collada ie; .dae format and use Collada2POD converter to get .pod file. Later add action to it as it is done for hello-world sample

Comment: Hi Meera, I have the problem loading pod file in cocos3d project. My issue is little different, it shows the pod file what i created using blender->dae->pod , but the output of the image is black shaded(darken). Please see my queries here, (i) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025670/cocos3d-pod-output-doesnt-proper-and-black-shaded   (ii) http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/230244  and help resolving this, i need your help urgently.

Comment: I think, i am using Blender 2.65. is this the problem?

Comment: Hi Meera, Looks like not adding texture is the problem. Here is my code below, please advise me how to add texture image in my project code, so that it will reflect in the model? CC3PODResourceNode* podRezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName: @"RobotPODRez"]; podRezNode.resource = [IntroducingPODResource resourceFromFile: @"home.pod"]; podRezNode.location = cc3v(100.0, -90.0, 500.0); // If you want to stop the robot arm from being animated, uncomment the following line. podRezNode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO; podRezNode.isTouchEnabled = YES; [self addChild: podRezNode];

Comment: Try adding texture. Did you add the texture?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your pod file. How are you exporting pod file? Do something like exporting to collada and then use a collada to POD converter to get the required .pod files. I had some issues with blender before. They require python files to be added for additional functionalities. May be you are missing some. Try going through some tutorials. I had been working in cocos for a few days so can't tell you in detail the reason. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Check this in creating POD files 1. http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/ & 2. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28872 . Also go through tutorials of Bill Hollings